# i want to update checkbox value in db based on other checkbox value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i want to update my checkbox values into database based on other checkbox value problem if I have checked 8 check boxes 8 checkbox values are inserted with status='yes' again unchecked one checkbox with status='no' my problem is, if I unchecked  one check box the status is changed but previous check box values are inserted again i want to update those checkbox value with time.get me over this.i want to update my already checked check box value based on another checkbox value...

```
<script>
 $("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function () {
        var ids = [];
        var dis = [];
        $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
            ids.push($(this).val());
        });
        $('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').each(function(){
            dis.push($(this).val());
            });
            dis=dis.toString();
           ids=ids.toString();
        $.ajax({
            url: "bodcheckbox.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            data: ({value: ids,
                      unchecked:dis,
                      }),
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {
             alert("activitysubmitted");
            }
        });
    }); 

 </script>  
<?php
session_start();
include'config.php';
$username=$_SESSION['username'];

//if(isset($_POST['value']))
//{
 //unchecked box value--
$unchecked=$_POST['unchecked'];
$uncheckboxvalue=array();
$uncheckboxvalue=explode(",",$unchecked);
//--checkedbox value--
$checkbox=array();
$checklist=$_POST['value'];
$checkbox=explode(",",$checklist);
$currentdate = date('d-m-Y');
$year = date('Y', strtotime($currentdate));

$month = date('F', strtotime($currentdate));
$date=date('d',strtotime($currentdate));
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$currenttime=date("h-i-sa");
if(!empty($checklist)&& empty($unchecked))
{
 foreach($checkbox as $check)
     {
    $bod_insert=mysql_query("insert into bod(username,activityname,tickeddate,tickedtime,status)values('$username','".mysql_real_escape_string(      $check)."','$date-$month-$year','$currenttime','yes')",$conn);
     }
     foreach($uncheckboxvalue as $uncheck)
     {
      $bod_update=mysql_query("update bod set status='no' where activityname='".mysql_real_escape_string( $uncheck)."' and username='$username'",$conn);
     }
}

else    
{
    foreach($checbox as $check)
    {
    $bod_update=mysql_query("update bod set status='yes' tickedtime='$currenttime',tickeddate='$date-$month-$year' where activityname=''".        mysql_real_escape_string( $check)."'",$conn);
    }
    foreach($uncheckboxvalue as $uncheck)
     {
      $bod_update=mysql_query("update bod set status='no' where activityname='".mysql_real_escape_string( $uncheck)."' and username='$username'",$conn);
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: checkbox only posts if they are checked if uncheck they dont post

Comment: no Gert look at my code i can get my value of unchecked checkbox value.  it.my problem is when I uncheck the particular inbox i dont want to insert previously checked check box values instead i have to update those checkbox values

Comment: you cant because html doesnt post unchecked boxes , you have to add another input then compare it in php , if box 2 is uncheck $_POST["box2"] will = null not unchecked and the array will be messed up

Comment: better use radio buttons and hide one then compare if both choosen or only 1 choosen in php

Comment: thank you gert i got some idea by your valuable comments but i have to use check box in my task